# .htaccess rewrite - change ? to &

Tags: url-rewriting

My payment gateway redirects successful orders to the following url:

```
https://example.com/checkout/order-received/33510/?key=wc_order_5b47427fe053c?params=...
```

I need to rewrite this to:

```
https://example.com/checkout/order-received/33510/?key=wc_order_5b47427fe053c&params=...
```

The URL I am sending to the payment gateway already has a Query String and the gateway is appending another string to it using a ? instead of an &.

How can I change the second ? into an &?

Can someone help, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^((?:.+)?)\?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(checkout/order-received/.+)/(.*)$ /$1/?%1&%2 [L,QSD,NE,R]
```